# I get an error { "error": "Invalid email or password" }

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to implement the ability to log in to my account, he says that I have the wrong email or password, but I checked the correct email and password through the administrative line. help me understand why the error comes out and how to fix it

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    # def get(self, request):
    #     return render(request, 'login.html')

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid email or password'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(
            username=data['email'],
            password=data['password']
        )
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Неверные учетные данные')

        data['user'] = user
        return data

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Comment: Could you share your error traceback? It looks like you're authenticating twice, one time on the View and another on the Serializer. Try to remove the `serializer_class = LoginSerializer` from the view to see what happens.

Comment: {
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}                                                                       this returns

Comment: By the message, it seems you're doing a GET request instead of a POST request. How are you making the request?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.